# How can i see the error of back end side when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

How can i see the error of back end side when using ajax

When I'am having an error in the back end side i'm only getting internal server error and I don't know exactly how to debug it and I'm having a hard time debugging.

Is there a way to see the error on the back end side?

I'm using laravel by the way

Comment: Does the backend have log/error files for the http server?

Comment: You can see the response in development panel of your browser

Comment: js will only be able to report on what it's provided.   If you're getting a 500 'Server Error' and checked all the various messages and headers, then the server is not providing the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install laravel debug bar for your project with composer

and then enable capture_ajax in config and capture ajax exception

for install it : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using the network panel in browser is the most convenient way to debug ajax responses.

Also you can try to use the aplication which is called "Postman"( available in the chrome store. )